# Ember array not updating template

Tags: ember.js, ember-select

Whats the likely cause of when you update an array in the controller and the update is not shown in the view (where as it works when the page loads initially).

My action that does the update:

```
  submit: function (foo) {
      let arr = this.get("baa");
      arr.push(foo);
      this.set("items", arr);
    }
```

template:

```
 {{view "select" content=items   class="form-control"}}
```

anything thats pushed is not reflected in the rendered select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you aren't using Ember Arrays. Try .pushObject instead of .push.

```
arr = Em.A()
arr.pushObject()
```

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html
"It is important to use the methods in this class to modify arrays so that changes are observable. This allows the binding system in Ember to function correctly."

Comment: thanks that worked, however this is sort not:    sort: function () {
      let arr = this.get("items");
      arr = arr.sort();
      this.set("items", arr);
    }

Comment: the items are staying in the same order in the template, but the array has changed

Comment: Saved my day. Using ember defined functions is the key